# Extract different variations of hyphenated personal names with regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I need to extract names after titles but I need to include hyphenated names too which can come in different variations.
The script below fails to pick up hyphenated names.

```
    text = 'This is the text where Lord Lee-How and Sir Alex Smith are mentioned.\
     Dame Ane Paul-Law is mentioned too. And just Lady Ball.'
    names = re.compile(r'(Lord|Baroness|Lady|Baron|Dame|Sir) ([A-Z][a-z]+)[ ]?([A-Z][a-z]+)?')
    names_with_titles = list(set(peers.findall(text)))  
    print(names_with_titles)
```

The current output is:

```
[('Lord', 'Lee', ''), ('Sir', 'Alex', 'Smith'), ('Dame', 'Ane', 'Paul'), ('Lady', 'Ball', '')]
```

The desired output should be:

```
[('Lord', 'Lee-How', ''), ('Sir', 'Alex', 'Smith'), ('Dame', 'Ane', 'Paul-Law'), ('Lady', 'Ball', '')]
```

I managed to extract hyphenated names with this pattern -

```
hyph_names = re.compile(r'(Lord|Baroness|Lady|Baron|Dame|Sir) ([A-Z]\w+(?=[\s\-][A-Z])(?:[\s\-][A-Z]\w+)+)')
```

But I cannot figure out how to combine the two. Will appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add a `(?:-[A-Z][a-z]+)?` optional group to the name part patterns:

```
(Lord|Baroness|Lady|Baron|Dame|Sir)\s+([A-Z][a-z]+(?:-[A-Z][a-z]+)?)(?:\s+([A-Z][a-z]+(?:-[A-Z][a-z]+)?))?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZCXRQm/1)

**Details**

- `(Lord|Baroness|Lady|Baron|Dame|Sir)` - one of the titles
- `\s+` - one or more whitespace chars
- `([A-Z][a-z]+(?:-[A-Z][a-z]+)?)` - a capturing group #1:

  - `[A-Z][a-z]+` - an uppercase letter followed with 1+ lowercase ones
  - `(?:-[A-Z][a-z]+)?`  - an optional non-capturing group matching a hyphen and then an uppercase letter followed with 1+ lowercase ones
- `(?:\s+([A-Z][a-z]+(?:-[A-Z][a-z]+)?))?` - an optional non-capturing group:

  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `([A-Z][a-z]+(?:-[A-Z][a-z]+)?)` - a capturing group #2 with the same pattern as in Group 1.

You may build it in Python 3.7 like

```
title = r'(Lord|Baroness|Lady|Baron|Dame|Sir)'
name = r'([A-Z][a-z]+(?:-[A-Z][a-z]+)?)'
rx = rf'{title}\s+{name}(?:\s+{name})?'
```

In older versions,

```
rx = r'{0}\s+{1}(?:\s+{1})?'.format(title, name)
```